# Returning one of many types from a string

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method.

```
private T Blah<T>()
```

In this method I have a string that I want to return, but the problem is that `T` may not be a string.  The values `T` can be are `string`, `int`, `DateTime`, `DateTime?` and `decimal?`.

What do I do to this string so that I can return it and support all these types?

Comment: What is the goal of having a generic type when you know it will always return a string?

Comment: No, what I mean is that in the code I have a string that I want to return.  If T is DateTime, then I want to convert that string to DateTime and return it, if it is a decimal then I want to concert to decimal and return it etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  private T Blah<T> () where T : IConvertible
  {            
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
          return (T)Convert.ChangeType(source, typeof(T));
     return default(T);
  }
```

Should work for all those types.

Comment: Then use Convert and require that T implement IConvertable... I'll update my answer for you =)

Comment: @SachinKainth, define elegant.

Comment: @Anthony that was before my answer WAS elegant =)

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
private T Blah<T>(Func<string, T> map)
{   
    //Your codes here

    return map(yourString); //yourString: the string which you are going to convert
}
```

Here you call it:

```
//For int
Blah(input => int.Parse(input));

//For DateTime
Blah(input => DateTime.Parse(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

I made `Blah<T>` *public* for test, modify it as your requirement.

- Code

  ```
  partial class SomeClass {
      public T Blah<T>() {
          var t="2013 03 30";

          return (T)(typeof(String).Equals(typeof(T))?t as object:(
              from args in new[] { new object[] { t, default(T) } }
              let type=Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T))??typeof(T)
              let types=new[] { typeof(String), type.MakeByRefType() }
              let bindingAttr=BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static
              let tryParse=type.GetMethod("TryParse", bindingAttr, default(Binder), types, null)
              let b=typeof(DateTime)!=type
              let dummy=b?args[0]=((String)args[0]).Split('\x20').Aggregate(String.Concat):""
              let success=null!=tryParse?tryParse.Invoke(typeof(T), args):false
              select args.Last()).Last());
      }
  }
  ```

  ```
  partial class TestClass {
      public static void TestMethod() {
          var x=new SomeClass();

          Console.WriteLine("x.Blah<String>() = {0}", x.Blah<String>());
          Console.WriteLine("x.Blah<int>() = {0}", x.Blah<int>());
          Console.WriteLine("x.Blah<DateTime>() = {0}", x.Blah<DateTime>());
          Console.WriteLine("x.Blah<DateTime?>() = {0}", x.Blah<DateTime?>());
          Console.WriteLine("x.Blah<decimal?>() = {0}", x.Blah<decimal?>());
      }
  }
  ```
- Output

  ```
  x.Blah<String>() = 2013 03 30
  x.Blah<int>() = 20130330
  x.Blah<DateTime>() = 2013/3/30 0:00:00
  x.Blah<DateTime?>() = 2013/3/30 0:00:00
  x.Blah<decimal?>() = 20130330
  ```

The special thing is that I removed the spaces if destination type is not `DateTime` or `DateTime?`.

You can even try with `x.Blah<long>()` which is not in your requirement, and any other types. Let me know if you found **any** type can cause an exception.